# Sign language action name verb

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, terminology

What is the proper way to speak about the action of carrying out sign language without being repetitive?

- to speak sign language
  (seems to imply using voice and mouth)
- to sign sign language
  (is repetitive)
- to sign
  (people might just think one was making just a one-off specific gesture as opposed to being engaged in the process of speaking a full language)

Thanks.

Comment: Try *to perform*.

Comment: .. to **use** sign language?

Comment: I think "to use" is probably most appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: It would depend on the context. If it were clear that I'm narrating what someone's communicating in sign language, I would use mostly the same verbs as for speech. *Said* carries the general meaning *expressed,* and is normally repeated often. So, *asked, replied, indicated, repeated,* and even something like *yelled,* which is communicated in sign language.

Comment: Interesting. So I guess even in sign language one can tell or speak softly. :-) Thanks.

Comment: There is some yelling in American Sign Language here: https://youtu.be/9SGCF7aBl1k

Comment: I think the idiomatic way to phrase is just *to sign*.  If there's enough context, it should be obvious that you're referring to deaf people using sign language, and not (for example) somebody signing a check or just gesturing.

Comment: @JackMaddington This question actually arose in conversation last week with a friend who is fluent in ASL. He decided that the proper usage would be: _To **sign** in [language],_ e.g.: _I signed in ASL._

Comment: See this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258383/does-one-speak-a-sign-language

Comment: It is certainly possible to be "loud" in sign. I had a friend who was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct verb is "to sign". And you would use it like so:

> He was signing so fast I could barely keep up.
>
> Sorry, I don't sign.

Since this is the only intransitive use of this verb, your meaning should be clear (within the constraint that this is not a top-of-mind activity for most people.)

Note that a person who signs for a living is an "interpreter", not a "translator".